# GNU-parallel : how to pass a variable which has {} and / as args

Tags: linux, networking

```
echo $ip
197.167.{2..61}.0/24
```

(this is range of ip 197.167.2.0/24 to 197.167.61.0/24)
I want to ping all possible ips in the above range.

```
~# parallel -k -j 0 --tag --verbose -q  fping -a -r 1 -g -q -s ::: $ip
time fping -a -r 1 -g -q -s 197.167.\{2..61\}.0/24
197.167.{2..61}.0/24    Error: can't parse address 197.167.{2..61}.0: Name or service not known
```

this works

```
parallel -k -j 0 --tag --verbose -q time fping -a -r 1 -g -q -s ::: 197.167.{2..61}.0/24
```

So how do i pass the subnet range var $ip to parallel ?

```
parallel -k -j 0 --tag --verbose -q time fping -a -r 1 -g -q -s ::: $ip
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
eval parallel -k -j 0 --tag --verbose -q time fping -a -r 1 -g -q -s ::: $ip
```